# failed to retrieve a local variable

Tags: javascript

I'm a JS self-learner. I want to make a playlist using select HTML element and a button. I managed to choose and console log the value from the  but I can't use it to create the name of an MP3 file. Can anyone give me a hand? I read that var has both local and global scope. Or how can I retrieve the value from the selectTrack function. Sorry if for some of you it may be a trivial question but I'm still on the stage of figuring out the functions in JS.

```
    <div class="playlist-container">
      <select class="playlist-selector" onchange="selectTrack()">
        <option value="default">default</option>
        <option value="track1">Owner of a Lonely Heart</option>
        <option value="track2">Somebody's Baby</option>
        <option value="track3">Easy Lover</option>
      </select>
      <button class="play-btn">play</button>
    </div>
```

```
  const playBtn = document.querySelector(".play-btn");
let mySong = ``

function selectTrack() {
    var mySongSelected = document.querySelector(".playlist-selector").value;
    console.log(mySongSelected);
  }

playBtn.addEventListener("click", playTrack);

function playTrack() {
    console.log(`${mySongSelected}.mp3`);
}
```

Comment: `mySong = mySongSelected` ```console.log(`${mySong}.mp3`)```…?!

Comment: Don't use var for variables.  Use let and const as appropriate to your needs.   Your problem is that mySongSelected isn't available within playTrack.  Define it in document scope using `let mySongSelected = ''`.  Remove the `var` keyword inside selectTrack().

Comment: Thats because mySongSelected is in the scope of the "selectTrack" function. "mySong" seems redundant so assign "document.querySelector(".playlist-selector").value;" to mySong

Comment: Within playTrack, you could just get the value again from the select, like you did in selectTrack.

Comment: So when I declare a global variable and then use the same variable in the function which modifies it or assign some value to it, the modified variable is global? Right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed your onchange and selectTrack function, then declared mySong as undefined and initialized it inside playTrack with the queryselector.value as its value. Now it seems to work fine.

HTML

```
  <div class="playlist-container">
      <select class="playlist-selector" >
        <option value="default">default</option>
        <option value="track1">Owner of a Lonely Heart</option>
        <option value="track2">Somebody's Baby</option>
        <option value="track3">Easy Lover</option>
      </select>
      <button class="play-btn">play</button>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play-btn')
let mySong;

playBtn.addEventListener('click', playTrack)

function playTrack() {
  mySong = document.querySelector('.playlist-selector').value
  console.log(`${mySong}.mp3`)
}
```